# Effect of integrable function on convergence

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to understand how multiplying by or adding a Lebesgue integrable function to a sequence of functions affects the convergence

Say $g(x) \in \mathscr{L^1}(\lambda)$. That is $g(x)$ is measurable and $ \int g(x)d\lambda < \infty$.
We have to sequences:
$$a_n(x)=f_n(x)g(x)=n^{-1}\chi_{[0,n)}(x) \cdot g(x)$$

Here although $f_n(x)$ does not converge in $L^1$ it converges in $L^\infty$ which implies $a_n$ converges in $L^1$. $f_n$ converges point wise to $0$ but can we say anything about the point wise convergence of $a_n$.
I know since $L^1$ is complete, $a_n$ is Cauchy and therefore has a convergent subsequence.

What about a sequence like
$$b_n(x)=n^{-1}\chi_{[0,1/n)} +g(x)$$

What restrictions do we need for convergence in $L^p$ to mean point wise convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some sort of "multiplier", one goes with the Holder's inequality to see what further properties we can get: $\|uv\|_{L^{r}}\leq\|u\|_{L^{p}}\|v\|_{L^{q}}$, where $\dfrac{1}{r}=\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{q}$, $1\leq r,p,q\leq\infty$ with the convention that $\dfrac{1}{\infty}=0$, $\dfrac{1}{0}=\infty$.

For the $L^{p}$ convergence, this only implies that there is a subsequence who converges a.e., there is hardly anything to say about the a.e. convergence of the original sequence.

Comment: Idk why it seems to me the first sequence has to also converge

Comment: $\|a_{n}\|_{L^{1}}=\|f_{n}g\|_{L^{1}}\leq\|f_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}}\|g\|_{L^{1}}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I meant point wise

Comment: No, that would not be the case. Only a.e. pointwise for a subsequence.

Comment: But for $b_{n}$, yes, it is the case, $b_{n}(x)\rightarrow g(x)$ a.e. I think you made a typo for $b_{n}$, it should be $n^{-1}\chi_{[0,n)}$, not $n^{-1}\chi_{[0,1/n)}$.

Comment: I thought I did too but it's actually $1/n$. Second sequence converges in $L^1$ as well with the same reasoning as the first sequence I suppose

Comment: Okay, it goes through as well, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Don't be sorry, you're the only person willing to help you're a saint in my book